# Laravel Eloquent ORM - With Query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm

I am trying to acheieve a [`WITH`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) by combining two of the same models.

Since model is using left joins on a has many relationship, I am having to `distinct` to ensure duplicate rows do not show.

I want to take the Builder and basically do:

```
WITH (model with left join) as list
SELECT * from list ORDER BY some_column DESC
```

The problem I have is I cannot find a function to take data from another model anywhere, I have tried the following:

```
# Pull through latest records from blah
$builder = Model::query()->distinct('models.id')->leftJoin('blah', 'blah.id', '=', 'models.blah_id')->orderByRaw('models.id, blah.created_at desc');

# With the builder, select from the With
Model::from($builder)->select(['*'])->orderBy('created_at')->get();
```

The issue is, the `from` method always expects a string.. I want to just load it from another model. Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a subquery by utilizing the `fromSub` method to achieve what you want.

```
$builder = Model::query()
    ->select('models.*')
    ->distinct('models.id')
    ->leftJoin('blah', 'blah.id', '=', 'models.blah_id')
    ->orderBy('models.id')
    ->orderByDesc('blah.created_at');

$results = Model::fromSub($builder, 'list')
    ->orderBy('list.created_at')
    ->get();
```